# Two 32bit addtion in ALU

Tags: binary, addition, multiplication

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56488/parallel-multiplication-hardware/56518#56518

I was looking for the question about the multiple adders.

And the answer says that a wider adders is needed as the tree move down.

Suppose, I multiply two 32bits numbers.

Let's say in first layer I add two 32bis number in 16 parallel adders.

Then the answer says the result would be sixteen 34bits.

But if we add two 32bits is it enough with the 33bits long?

We can represent the overflow and sign with only one additional bits.

Why we need 34bits adder instead of 33bits long?

Here's another link with the similar question.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/95733/difficulty-understanding-the-faster-multiplication-hardware

Comment: "Suppose, I multiply two 32bits numbers." don't you mean "add" ?

Comment: I mean using addition parrallel for the multiplication